# Is it safe to upgrade appstream if APT has kept it back?

Tags: apt, upgrade, appstream

I ran `apt upgrade` the other day, and got this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  appstream
```

According to a related question somewhere on this site, appstream is safe to even remove.

How do I know if upgrading it is safe, and what will the upgrade actually change in my system? I'm assuming apt has kept it back for a reason, so I wanted to play safe before I run `dist-upgrade`.

Here's what `changelog` has to say:

```
appstream (0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1) xenial-backports; urgency=medium

  * Backport to 16.04, with one change:
   - Lower the required Qt version to 5.4

 -- Iain Lane <iain@orangesquash.org.uk>  Wed, 01 Feb 2017 12:02:22 +0000
```

I'm assuming this won't brake anything?

`apt-get -s dist-upgrade` (even with `sudo`), as proposed by @muru, yielded nothing new, except the same old message that `appstream` has been kept back.

Here's the output of `apt-get -s install appstream`:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-software-common libgtkspell3-3-0 libsnapd-glib1 snapd-login-service
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  gnome-software ubuntu-software
The following packages will be upgraded:
  appstream
```

Comment: if it is held back, try `apt-get -s dist-upgrade` and see what it will do when upgrading. Probably an added dependency or something.

Comment: @muru  -  it only says that this package has been held back, nothing new. I even tries with `sudo`

Comment: Even with `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @muru  -  yep, same. I'll try `apt install appstream`, but I wanted to check here if it's safe. Is there an option to run `install` in a sort of "read-only" mode, to see what'll happen?

Comment: with apt-get the option is `-s`, iirc. Not sure what option is for apt. Probably the same.

Comment: @muru  -  see updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per `apt show appstream`, version `0.10.16-1` of `appstream` breaks versions of `gnome-software` below `3.22.5-1`, and the version of `gnome-software` in Xenial is `3.20.1`. Hence, this version of `appstream` cannot be installed on a Xenial system together with `gnome-software`.

By the way, this seems like a good time to remember that [backports are supposed to be installed manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Stability_of_Backports) on an as-needed basis. Although you can enable automatic installation of backports, you do so at your own risk, as it can cause issues like the one you are seeing now.

Comment: Thanks for warning about backports! I disabled them and that appstream update disappeared.

Comment: @Gallifreyan If you disabled backports, you should look if you have any backport packages installed (*e.g.*, `apt list --installed | grep backports`), and if so, revert them to the official version, so you don't have an unmaintained version installed.

Comment: I only got an error about `APT` not having a stable cli, so I guess I have no backports

Comment: Warnings are not errors, but yes.

Comment: I had the same situation as you today.  I had libappstream4 from backports, it may have been installed today as well.