# Update after purging Intel 01.org driver removed gnome-software

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-center, dependencies, backport

Since I upgraded my GPU, I removed the Intel's Open Source Technology Center Driver following [the procedure from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343390/how-to-remove-intels-open-source-technology-center-driver).

By doing so a bunch of software was downgraded as expected but some other kinda unrelated were removed.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-software-common libgtkspell3-3-0 libmowgli-2-0 libqt5keychain1 libqtkeychain1 libsnapd-glib1
  snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-software libnvpair1 libuutil1 libzfs2 libzpool2 ubuntu-software ubuntu-zfs zfsutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autopoint dh-autoreconf libcrypto++9v5 libltdl-dev libqt5keychain0 libtool libuv1 m4
The following packages will be upgraded:
  appstream debhelper libappstream4 libarchive13
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libguess1 libowncloudsync0 libshairplay0 mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui nethogs nodejs owncloud-client
  owncloud-client-l10n spl spl-dkms synergy xboxdrv zfs-dkms zfs-doc
```

Among those were `gnome-software` and `ubuntu-software`. If I try to reinstall them I get a dependency error:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-software : Depends: appstream but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the output of `apt policy appstream`:

```
  Installed: 0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1 100
        100 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.3-1~ubuntu16.04~ppa2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     0.9.4-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.9.4-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Everything points to the backports repos messing things up, but I find it strange that the developers didn't noticed such an obvious problem and that thought leads me to think that the true problem is somewhere else. What can I do to fix the Software Center?

I'm on Ubuntu Unity x86_64 16.04

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/878995/256317

Comment: However, here it is unclear why the backports version of `appstream` was installed, since automatic installation of backports was not enabled... In any case, downgrading `appstream` to a lower version will probably do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou @fkraiem . Did that by `sudo apt install appstream=0.10.3-1~ubuntu16.04~ppa2` which is the immediate previous version and then could install `gnome-software` without problems.

Comment: Great, you can now answer your own question. :)

Comment: By the way, since you said you just removed a repository, I think the reason why `appstream` was upgraded to the backports version is that you used to have a version between `0.10.3` and `0.10.6`, which was provided by the old repository. When that repository was removed, that version was no longer available, so the package was upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/878995/256317), `appstream 0.10.16-1` is incompatible with `gnome-software 3.22.5-1` which is shipped with Xenial.

By installing the immediate previous version of `appstream` the re-installation of `gnome-software` should be posible again.

To know the exact number of said version run `apt policy appstream` in a terminal. Then copy and paste the number and install said version in this way:

```
apt install appstream=0.10.3-1~ubuntu16.04~ppa2
```

Since I got KDE Backports PPA enabled that is my corresponding version, but depending on your active PPAs you may have a different "latest" version.

Then reinstall the previously removed packages:

```
apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
```

This will bring back the software but the icon will be different now.